# HTML5 'Required' tag not working in Safari

Tags: html, forms, validation, safari

My html5 input types' required tags are not working in Safari. When I try to submit without filling in the required fields, it just goes through. :( It supposed to have warning or reminder telling to fill in the fields.

Please help me. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Safari doesn't (yet) support that feature of the HTML 5 Candidate Recommendation.

Either implement a JavaScript shim, or depend on your server side validation in Safari.

Comment: Do you any Javascript that could work? I tried the script in here http://forums.asp.net/t/1911017.aspx?Field+Validation+for+browsers+not+supporting+html5+required+attribute

.. but it's not working. :(

Answer (score 0):

Safari doesn't support HTML5 validation, you can use [Webshim](http://afarkas.github.io/webshim/demos/) (a polyfill library that enables you to reliably use HTML5 features across browsers, even if native support is lacking).

Answer (score 0):

Safari doesn't currently support this but it's coming in Safari 10.1 (the next release).

In the mean time there are some nice javascript workarounds in the post [Required Attribute Not work in Safari Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23261301/required-attribute-not-work-in-safari-browser)