# onSubmit on form not going through HTML5 validator

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I’m trying to have a javascript function run AFTER a form has been submitted and validated. When I use onSubmit, the function runs regardless. The basic HTML5 validator (For example the REQUIRED tag) does not run.

When I remove the onSubmit, the HTML5 validator works perfectly, showing a message if a required field is blank.

I would like the function to be run only after a successful submission, where the required fields are filled in.

Here is my current code:

```
<form id="form" method="POST" action="//api.cloudstitch.io/test/test/datasources/sheet" class="form" onSubmit="goPush()" >
  <div class="form-group">
    <label><b>First Name </b></label>
    <input name="FirstName" class="form-control">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label><b>Last Name </b></label>
    <input name="LastName" class="form-control" required >
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="submit">Submit</input>
  </div>
</form>
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Updated:

Here is the function that’s being run on the onSubmit.

```
 <script>
var goPush = function(){parent.window.myhypedocument.showSceneNamed(‘mycard');};
    </script>
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: We will need the js code being used

Comment: Once a form is submitted, navigation occurs. You're no longer on the same page.

Comment: You will need AJAX to do a (a)synchronous http (server) request.

Comment: `showSceneNamed(‘mycard')` – is that just a typo?

Comment: Yep @CBroe, just a typo haha

Comment: Seems to work just fine - http://jsfiddle.net/pha0yrzu/3/ in  Chrome 46.0.2490.80 m.
The JS function gets executed only when all required fields are filled.

Comment: Strange, that’s not working in Safari for me

Comment: Oh, Safari. It does not seem to have full support for these attributes - http://caniuse.com/#search=required. Here is a post that discusses the issue and provides alternatives - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23261301/required-attribute-not-work-in-safari-browser