# Symfony2 form validation Safari

Tags: php, html, forms, symfony, safari

Well,I actually tested my form code in Chrome, Firefox and IE, but then when a friend tested my form in his Mac I discovered that the required field doesn't worked, because Safari doesn't accept the required class. So, at the end of the form when I press the send button I got the database error and it crashes.

I searched into the Symfony documentation and I found this piece of code on the form class:

```
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver) {
    $collectionConstraint = new Collection(array(
    'name' => array(
        new NotBlank(array('message' => 'Name should not be blank.')),
    )
    ));

    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'constraints' => $collectionConstraint
    ));
}
```

But it seems to do nothing. Also I put on the Entity class this:

```
/**
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 */
public $name;
```

And still get the error. Any ideas what am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with Safari is that it recognizes the HTML5 required attribute but it doesn't stop the form from being submited. You need to use javascript to check it.

[This post should help with that.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23261301/required-attribute-not-work-in-safari-browser)

Comment: this is spot on, but also you need to be still validating server side anyways.  **never** rely on client side validation alone.

Comment: He'll have to check the form server-side yes, but he should already be doing that really because HTML5 validation can be worked around.