# Validate multiple fields on button click only using Jquery

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-mobile

I am using Jquery Mobile, Jquery. I have three **data-role="page"**. I have three different **ID** for three different pages. Now I need to validate multiple fields which is there in *2nd* **data-role="page"**.

In the second page, i have static dropdowns and some text boxes. On selection of the dropdown i am displaying some more fields into the page. *On button click* i need to validate the newly displayed fields.

```
if (LOCATIONOne_Sel_Val=='')
    {
        if($('#errorLocOne').length) 
        {
            return false; //If the error Message is displayed already
        }
        else //Display the error message
        {
            $(errorMsgLocOne).insertAfter('#Loc_Id1');
            return false;
        }
    }
else if(LOCATIONTwo_Sel_Val=='')
    {
    if($('#errorLocTwo').length) 
        {
            return false; //If the error Message is displayed already
        }
        else //Display the error message
        {
            $(errorMsgLocTwo).insertAfter('#Loc_Id2');
            return false;
        }
    }
```

In the above code, If i select some value in **LOCATIONTwo_Sel_Val** dropdown then one more drop down will be displayed. I need to validate that too for a null Value.

Like this i have 15 fields to validate. How can i achieve this in a better way?

NOTE: I am **not** using Validation plugin. **Dont** want to use that.

Comment: Use `required` attribute.

Comment: @Tushar, how can i use it for Dropdown fields?

Comment: Not all browsers support `required`. You need JavaScript to perform client side validation. However, you can use `required` in combination with JavaScript / jQuery, like this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23261301/required-attribute-not-work-in-safari-browser#answer-31319587

Comment: Apply the `required` attribute to selectmenus like this: `<select name="foo" required>`