# some_input.prop('required', true); doesn't work in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, safari

The below code works in Chrome but not Safari.

```
var some_input = $("input[name$='/some_input']");
some_input.prop('required', true);
```

Could you please explain how to fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Required Attribute Not work in Safari Browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23261301/required-attribute-not-work-in-safari-browser)

Comment: Have you tried: `some_input.required = true;` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this, maybe it helps.

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_attr.asp