# Onsubmit function is firing on Safari, even though the required input is empty

Tags: javascript, html, required, onsubmit, webshim

**Required** attribute is not working in Safari.

To fix this, I'm using Webshim. It was all working perfectly, until I noticed that when I use **onsubmit** on the form tag, it fires when you submit, no matter that there are some required inputs empty. 
You see the "Please fill out this field" on the input, but the onsubmit functions fires anyway.

```
<form onsubmit="alert('hi')" action="#">
  <input placeholder="native input works" required>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

This is how I initialize Webshim:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/webshim/1.16.0/dev/polyfiller.js"></script>
    <script> 
        webshim.activeLang('en');
        webshims.polyfill('forms');
        webshims.cfg.no$Switch = true;
    </script>
```

Here you have a working Example. You can try it on Safari, and in Chrome, and you'll see the Alert firing on safari, and not in chrome.

https://jsfiddle.net/3pxsvxxj/

Please, I need to solve this, and I can't find a way.

Cheers.

Comment: Can you share the portion of code where you initialize webshim?

Comment: I'm sorry Santi, I forgot that detail. I added it to the post.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, Safari browser does not support the `required` attribute, as listed [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp).

If you refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23261301/required-attribute-not-work-in-safari-browser) question, it has alternatives which provide the functionality.

And since you said you are using webshim, refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35599959/4259027) answer from the question I linked which provides an example of using webshim:

> At this time, Safari doesn't support the "required" input attribute. http://caniuse.com/#search=required
>
> To use the 'required' attribute on Safari, You can use 'webshim'
>
> 1 - Download webshim
>
> 2 - Put this code :

```
<head>
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js-webshim/minified/polyfiller.js"></script>
    <script> 
        webshim.activeLang('en');
        webshims.polyfill('forms');
        webshims.cfg.no$Switch = true;
    </script>
</head>
```

Comment: Hi Mor, that's why I said that I used Webshim to solve the "required" not working on Safari. But not the problem that I described in the post.

Comment: Yes, I already have all that in my code. I added it to the post. Webshim solve my problem of the "Required" inputs, but it does not stop onsubmit function to fire.